# How would I change a pickle value for highscore?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am making a game in python and I want to add a system that saves the users highscore, and loads it the next time the application is run. To do this I am using pickle. I have been able to save the data, but I do not know how to edit the value stored in the pickle file.
Code(*to show what I want to do*):

```
import pickle
hs=0
savedhs=pickle.dumps(hs)
highscore=pickle.loads(savedhs)
hs=hs+1
print(highscore)
#Expected output: 1
#output:0
```

How would I make it so that whenever the value of **hs** changes, the pickled file also changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the pickled file, you could open it in write mode and update the value. Like this

```
import pickle

# Open the file in write mode
with open("highscore.pickle", "wb") as f:
    # Load the data from the file
    highscore = pickle.load(f)
    # Update the value of highscore
    highscore += 1
    # Write the updated value back to the file
    pickle.dump(highscore, f)
```